# how to navigate to different screens based on the user login if he is professional or not

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication

i have a project in which user can signup as professional and consumer. i using firebase for the database. in firebase i have a property isProfessional. when user login it should check if the user is professional nor not. and based on user login it navigate to different screens.

when i try to login this is the debugconsole output.

```
I/FirebaseAuth(11447): Logging in as professionala@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
2
W/System  (11447): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(11447): Notifying id token listeners about user ( 3VzjxEtS4eQAmMKOdzQZiGA1KaF2 ).
E/flutter (11447): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' has no instance method '[]'.
E/flutter (11447): Receiver: Instance of '_MapStream<QuerySnapshotPlatform, QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>'
E/flutter (11447): Tried calling: []("isProfessional")
E/flutter (11447): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (11447): #1      _LogInScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>
login.dart:267
E/flutter (11447): <asynchronous suspension>
```

and this is method

```
ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.orange, // Background color
                        onPrimary: Colors.white, // Text color
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        minimumSize: const Size(100, 40),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          isloading = true;
                        });

                        // Perform the login method
                        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                          // context: context,
                          email: emailController.text,
                          password: passwordController.text,
                        );
                        var userData =
                            await FireStoreServices.getUser(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
                        bool isProfessional = userData['isProfessional'];
                        print(isProfessional);

                        setState(() {
                          isloading = false;
                        });

                        if (isProfessional) {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement<void, void>(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  ProfessionalDashboard(),
                            ),
                          );
                        } else {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement<void, void>(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute<void>(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  ConsumerDashboard(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        // }
                        // );
                      },
                      child: isloading
                          ? CircularProgressIndicator(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          : const Text(
                              'Sign in',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                            ),
                    ),
```

Comment: Can you please show your FireStoreServices.getUser method?

Comment: here is it class FireStoreServices {

//get users data
  static getUser(uid){
    return firestore.collection(commonUserData).where('id', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();
  }

}

Answer (score 0):

As per your `getUser` function, it is returning `snapshots` of the data not `Map`.

If you want data in the `Map`, then you should modify that function as following:

```
class FireStoreServices {
  //get users data
  static getUser(uid) {
    QuerySnapshot data = await firestore.collection(commonUserData).where('id', isEqualTo: uid).limit(1).get();
    if (data.size > 0) {
      return data.docs.first.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now you will get `bool isProfessional = userData['isProfessional'];` in your statement.

and also check for null before you access inner data like :

```
if(userData != null) {
  bool isProfessional = userData['isProfessional'];
}
else {
//some error
}
```